# Why does this javascript code prevent my browser from ever loading?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm learning javascript and jquery and have written a very basic script inside my file.  I'm experiencing two problems...

1. The browser never finishes loading the document, it just sits there with the loading icon animating in the tab.  Any ideas?
2. I can't seem to debug this using firebug.  When I set a breakpoint anywhere in the document load function, it never hits.  Any ideas?

Here's my code...

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" href="default.css" rel="stylesheet">       
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        var strMarkup = "";
        var strXMLFile = "";

        //Parse XML and generate accordion elements
        var arrayAccordianElements = ParseXML(strXMLFile);

    }); 

    function ParseXML(strPath)
    {
        var arrayEvents = new Array();
        arrayEvents[0] = "test1";
        arrayEvents[1] = "test2";
        arrayEvents[2] = "test3";

        //Return the accordian elements
        return arrayEvents;
    }       
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    hello
</body>
</html>
```

As you experts can see, my webpage should simply display "hello" after processing some javascript that creates an array inside of a function.  Do you see any problems?  I apologize if they're obvious problems, I'm a noob :)

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Loads okay for me. IE shows an error.

Comment: Works for me in 4 browsers. What browser(s) are you testing with? What Firefox extensions are enabled? What happens when you restart the browser?

Comment: Works just fine for me in FF 3.5 with and without firebug

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but you may want to include a doctype so that browsers use standards mode rather than quirks mode.

Comment: thanks for checking, everyone, there must be something strange happening only on my machine.  the script seems to work fine in chrome and IE, but not firefox.

Comment: ok, i added the strict doctype and that seemed to make a big difference, but my page still loads forever...i'll keep messing around with it.  thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runs fine for me in Safari 4.0.3. Make sure your path to jQuery is correct? If it is incorrect and there's something misconfigured and jQuery fails to load, that will hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

Code-wise I don't see anything that would cause an infinite loop at all. However, knowing firefox etc, there may be a variety of things out of your control. Start with restarting the browser. Profile the script with Firebug (Console > Profile > Reload the page > Press profile again), and see what part takes most time.

One thing, probably unrelated, close your link tag.  is sufficient.

Comment: There's no need to close the link tag.

Comment: Why not? Each tag has an opening and a closure. Sure the old standards were rather forgiving so it is not **mandatory** to close it, but semantically you should.

Comment: er... why? I'm pretty sure that HTML 4-5 browsers are smart enough to auto-close tags where the end tag is forbidden (and it IS forbidden on meta and link tags).

Comment: In that case let's add more to the debate and say that it depends on your doctype. If it is XHTML then close your tags, otherwise don't since closing <link> is actually against HTML standard. Btw, relying on the browser is risky, you wouldn't leave <td> or <tr> unclosed would you?

Comment: @Dmitri: to an HTML parser, the /> construct is actually an ignorable error (an attribute with the invalid name "/" to be precise). Empty elements should only be explicitly closed that way in XML documents such as XHTML.